# iOS : Sliding tab layout with UITableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, customization

I am developing Sliding tab layout with the help of Swift 1.2. Sliding tab must have single `UITableView`.
`UITableView` will be refresh when I slide / move the tab.

I have tried many tutorials from other sources, but could not get proper hint as most of tutorial used separate `ViewControllers` for each tab. What i want is, to use single `ViewController` with one `UITableView` for all tabs.

How to achieve this in iOS - Swift?

Comment: If you post some code as to what you have tried, people would help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `pan gesture recognizer` on your tab view, track the movement to next tab on that view. When it does, reload your tableview's data.